# Sending email options in iOS5 app

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've got my iOS app sending out emails, where it generates the email form ready for the user to send using `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`. Now I'm just wondering if we can hide the `CC/Bcc` field and if we can choose not to include the users signature. I've looked around and not found anything in the API - am I barking up a non existant tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed barking up a non-existent tree.

You can, however:

Implement your own mail composer view (and probably your own mail sender code);

Look for an API that can help you with implementing that;

Try the private API calls (and Apple won't probably accept your app);

Comment: Hmm I guess the only real way to do it would be to push some data to a web API and then send the email on from there. It's only going back to us so it doesn't matter that much who it comes from.

Comment: Can you please close the question?